# How to Enable the product search by tags in magento store

Tags: magento, search, product

I am running a Magento store and have a search bar that is search for products. right now it is searching on the base of products names but i want to make it search by products tags.

I have created the new tags in Magento admin as follows:

```
Catalog > Tags
```

and then i have assign this tag to a products by:

```
Catalog > Manage products > tags
```

from left sidebar but it is  not searching i want to know how i can enable this function to search by tags also

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Magentos product search does not work for tags, just for name, description and attributes. If you want to include tags in the product search you need to use a custom module.

Comment: Can you suggest a free one?